# How to make a rails combobox (= constrained text field)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `collection_select`. The list of possible values is getting long, so the UI becomes ugly. I'd prefer the style of combo box where I type to help find one the items in the list, instead of only having a giant popup menu. Searching for 'combobox' in rails seems to show me examples of what I already have.

```
  %p
= f.label 'Reader'
= f.collection_select(:reader_id, Reader.order('name ASC'), :id, :name, { :include_blank => true })
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish that, you will probably need to use a JavaScript library like [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) or [Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/api) (to choose two out of probably dozens of examples). If I'm not mistaken Rails only uses the basic controls defined in HTML 4 & 5.